# why the flutter response received json did not deserialize

Tags: flutter

I am using [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) response to receive json response from server side in flutter, this is part of the code:

```
  @override
  Future onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    Response handleResponse = await autoLogin(response);
    Response handleAccessToken = await handleResponseByCode(handleResponse);
    return super.onResponse(handleAccessToken, handler);
  }
```

sometimes I found the dio Response auto deserialize the json result to `_InternalLinkedHashMap`, like this:

[image]

sometimes are not deserialize by default. Just receive string like this:

[image]

what should I do to make all response deserialize by default? add some response header? If the deserialize action not keep the same, the client code sometimes runs fine, sometimes failed. This is the interceptor of my project current using, which I am parse the response and do some AOP logic:

```
class AppInterceptors extends InterceptorsWrapper {
  @override
  Future<void> onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    if (!options.headers.containsKey("accessToken")) {
      String? accessToken = await SecureStorageUtil.getString("accessToken");
      options.headers["accessToken"] = accessToken??"";
    }
    handler.next(options);
  }

  @override
  Future onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    Response handleResponse = await autoLogin(response);
    Response handleAccessToken = await handleResponseByCode(handleResponse);
    return super.onResponse(handleAccessToken, handler);
  }
}
```

this is the json data that did not deserialize by default:

```
{
body: [
{
id: 1,
creator: 1,
name: "Like Music",
cover_url: "",
description: null,
subscribed: 1,
subscribed_count: 1,
comment_count: 1,
share_count: 1,
play_count: 1
}
],
statusCode: "200",
resultCode: "200"
}
```

BTW, this json data was generate on the server side by using rust  `serde_json` to serialize like this:

```
#[get("/v1/playlist")]
pub fn user_playlist() -> io::Result<String> {
    use schema::playlist::dsl::*;
    let connection = config::establish_connection();
    let results = playlist.filter(creator.eq(1))
        .limit(1)
        .load::<QueryPlaylist>(&connection)
        .expect("Error loading posts");
    let res = ApiResponse {
        body: results,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    let response_json = serde_json::to_string(&res).unwrap();
    return Ok(response_json);
}
```

Comment: Is the format cause did not deserialize by default? @pskink

Comment: response from the first picture is 100% JSON object. But in the second picture one doesn't look like JSON. Are you sure you are sending json object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check two things:

- In the `Options` of your request have you set the parameter `responseType` to `ResponseType.json`?
- Did the response have the header `content-type` valued `application/json`?

Dio set the parameter `responseType` to ResponseType.json by default only if the response has the header `content-type` valued `application/json`. (You can see it on the Dio's doc).